# how can I image (.png) hide when the metabox empty

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I want the button hide when it is empty remain unfortunately only the HTML before, even though the button is already empty, how can I rewrite the code so the button is hidden? I posted more details maybe someone can help me me

```
        function cspm_infobox_content(){

        $post_id = esc_attr($_POST['post_id']);
        $infobox_type = esc_attr($_POST['infobox_type']);
        $map_id = esc_attr($_POST['map_id']);
        $status = esc_attr($_POST['status']);
        $carousel = esc_attr($_POST['carousel']);
        $telnr = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'telnr', true );
        $telnr1 = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'telnr1', true );
        $email = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'email', true );
        $hane = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'hane', true );
        $marte = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'marte', true );
        $merkure = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'merkure', true );
        $enjte = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'enjte', true );
        $premte = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'premte', true );
        $shtune = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'shtune', true );
        $djele = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'djele', true );
        $shteti = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'shteti', true );
        $qyteti = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'qyteti', true );
        $rajoni = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'rajoni', true );
        $rruganr = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'rruganr', true );

        $no_title = array(); // Infoboxes to display with no title
        $no_link = array(); // Infobox to display whit no link
        $no_description = array('square_bubble', 'rounded_bubble', 'cspm_type2', 'cspm_type3', 'cspm_type4'); // Infoboxes to display with no description
        $no_image = array('cspm_type4'); // Infoboxes to display with no image



        if(!in_array($infobox_type, $no_title)) $item_title = apply_filters('cspm_custom_infobox_title', stripslashes_deep($this->cspm_items_title($post_id, $this->items_title)), $post_id); 
        if(!in_array($infobox_type, $no_description)) $item_description = apply_filters('cspm_custom_infobox_description', stripslashes_deep($this->cspm_items_details($post_id, $this->items_details)), $post_id);
        if(!in_array($infobox_type, $no_link)) $the_permalink = $this->cspm_get_permalink($post_id);

        if(!in_array($infobox_type, $no_image)){

            if($infobox_type == 'square_bubble' || $infobox_type == 'rounded_bubble')
                $parameter = array( 'style' => "width:50px; height:50px;" );
            elseif($infobox_type == 'cspm_type1')
                $parameter = array( 'style' => "width:100px; height:80px;" );
            elseif($infobox_type == 'cspm_type2')
                $parameter = array();
            elseif($infobox_type == 'cspm_type3' || $infobox_type == 'cspm_type5')
                $parameter = array( 'style' => "width:60px; height:60px;" );
            elseif($infobox_type == 'cspm_type4')
                $parameter = array();

            if($infobox_type == 'square_bubble' || $infobox_type == 'rounded_bubble'){
                $infobox_thumb = get_the_post_thumbnail($post_id, 'cspacing-marker-thumbnail', $parameter);
            }elseif($infobox_type == 'cspm_type1'){
                $infobox_thumb = get_the_post_thumbnail($post_id, 'cspacing-infobox1-thumbnail', $parameter);
            }else $infobox_thumb = get_the_post_thumbnail($post_id, 'cspacing-horizontal-thumbnail', $parameter);

            if(empty($infobox_thumb))
                $infobox_thumb = get_the_post_thumbnail($post_id, 'cspacing-horizontal-thumbnail', $parameter);

        }

        $post_thumbnail = apply_filters('cspm_infobox_thumb', $infobox_thumb, $post_id, $infobox_type, $parameter);

        $this->infobox_external_link = $this->cspm_get_setting('infoboxsettings', 'infobox_external_link', 'same_window');

        $target = ($this->infobox_external_link == 'new_window') ? ' target="_blank"' : ''; 
        $the_post_link = ($this->infobox_external_link == 'disable') ? $item_title : '<a href="'.$the_permalink.'" title="'.$item_title.'"'.$target.'>'.$item_title.'</a>'; 

        $output = '';

        $output .= '<div class="cspm_infobox_content_container '.$status.' infobox_'.$map_id.' '.$infobox_type.'" data-map-id="'.$map_id.'" data-post-id="'.$post_id.'" data-show-carousel="'.$carousel.'">';

            if($infobox_type == 'square_bubble' || $infobox_type == 'rounded_bubble'){

                $output .= '<div class="cspm_infobox_img">';
                    $output .= ($this->infobox_external_link != 'disable') ? '<a href="'.$the_permalink.'" title="'.$item_title.'"'.$target.'>'.$post_thumbnail.'</a>' : $post_thumbnail;
                $output .= '</div>';
                $output .= '<div class="cspm_arrow_down '.$infobox_type.'"></div>';

            }elseif($infobox_type == 'cspm_type1'){

                $output .= '<div class="cspm_infobox_img">'.$post_thumbnail.'</div>';
                $output .= '<div class="cspm_infobox_content">';
                    $output .= '<div class="title">'.$the_post_link.'</div>';
                    $output .= '<div class="description">'.$item_description.'</div>';
                $output .= '</div>';
                $output .= '<div style="clear:both"></div>';
                $output .= '<div class="cspm_arrow_down"></div>';

            }elseif($infobox_type == 'cspm_type2'){

                $output .= '<div class="cspm_infobox_img">'.$post_thumbnail.'</div>';
                $output .= '<div class="cspm_infobox_content">';
                    $output .= '<div class="title">'.$the_post_link.'</div>';
                $output .= '</div>';
                $output .= '<div class="cspm_arrow_down"></div>';

            }elseif($infobox_type == 'cspm_type3'){

                $output .= '<div class="cspm_infobox_img">'.$post_thumbnail.'</div>';
                $output .= '<div class="cspm_infobox_content">';
                    $output .= '<div class="title">'.$the_post_link.'</div>';
                $output .= '</div>';
                $output .= '<div class="cspm_arrow_down"></div>';

            }elseif($infobox_type == 'cspm_type4'){

                $output .= '<div class="cspm_infobox_content">';
                    $output .= '<div class="title">'.$the_post_link.'</div>';
                $output .= '</div>';
                $output .= '<div class="cspm_arrow_down"></div>';

            /**
             * @since 2.7 */

            }elseif($infobox_type == 'cspm_type5'){

                $output .= '<div class="cspm_infobox_content">';
                    $output .= '<div>';
                        $output .= '<div class="cspm_infobox_img">'.$post_thumbnail.'</div>';
                        $output .= '<div class="title">'.$the_post_link.'</div>';
                        $output .= '<div class="telnr"><a class="wm-button color-read" href="tel:'.$telnr.'"><img src="http://test.com/test/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/Phone-18-18-dimenzionet.png" height="18" width="18"></a>';
                        $output .= '<a class="wm-button color-read telnr1" style="left: 10px;" href="tel:'.$telnr1.'"><img src="http://test.com/test/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/Phone-18-18-dimenzionet.png" height="18" width="18"></a>';
                        $output .= '<a class="wm-button color-blue email" style="left: 20px;" href="mailto:'.$email.'?Subject=Un%20jam%20informuar%20për%20ju%20nga%20www.test.com&nbsp;"><img src="http://test.com/pinfo/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/email-ico.png" height="18" width="18"></a></div>';
```

Comment: you need to provide more code, also please describe the problem more clearly, you refer to the button as empty...  you're trying to either show or hide a button when some value is empty?  Please try to read your question and make sure it makes sense.

Comment: ok i have a Metabox in WooCommerce, and from there then loads the data in this plugin (progress map is the plugin) but if the metabox no text or numbers Hatt trozdem remains the button shown and I want it hidden

Comment: I can't find `hatt trozdem` anywhere in your code. `if (empty($var))` will tell you if a variable is empty, did you try that?

Comment: Yes I tried the but I can not make it, at the bottom are the 3 buttons with HTML, only there I can add that if there is a possibility to hide at least only .png

Comment: what is the variable that you want to check to make sure it's not empty? Let's pretend that variable is `$telnr1`, so if `$telnr1` is empty, you don't want to show the thumbnail, and let's pretend that thumbnail is `$post_thumbnail`.   So `if(!empty($telnr1)){echo $post_thumbnail;}`

Comment: Yes but that with $ telnr1 already works only,  the HTML with class = WM-button, and the image disappear .png not remain still there


<a class="wm-button color-read telnr1" style="left: 10px;" href="tel:'.$telnr1.'"><img src="http://porosija.com/pinfo/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/Phone-18-18-dimenzionet.png" height="18" width="18"></a>';

Comment: it is possible by a certain ID all the HTML to hide the fals value is instructive

Comment: Again, I do not understand the question, please give a complete description.  If you're trying to hide something else, put it in the if.  If you're trying to test if another value is empty, replace or combine it with $telnr1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if the value $ telnr1 is empty I want which is the whole HTML hidden below

```
<a class="wm-button color-read telnr1" style="left: 10px;" href="tel:'.$telnr1.'"><img src="../../wp-content/uploads/2015/06/Phone-18-18-dimenzionet.png" height="18" width="18"></a>
```